# Pyside: Unresolved Functions error messages on windows7

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyside

I tried to run a simple program that is written in python with PySide module to take screenshots of the websites. I'm running this program on a Windows 7 with OpenSSL(already installed).

I got the following errors:

```
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
```

Answer (score 0):

I by no means take credit for this solution as I did a simple google search and came across
http://codeblog.vurdalakov.net/2009/11/solution-qsslsocket-cannot-call.html

I believe the errors are a little different due to changes within the libraries.

Problem

When you try to open a HTTPS URL with `QSslSocket` or `QNetworkAccessManager` class, you get the following errors:

```
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_error_string
```

Solution

You need to install OpenSSL Win32 or Win64 binaries.

1. Open Win32 OpenSSL Installation Project page.
2. Download the latest "light" Win32 or Win64 installation package, for example "Win32 OpenSSL v0.9.8l Light".
3. Install it to any location. Ignore "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables" warning (click OK) and select copying OpenSSL DLLs to "The OpenSSL binaries (\bin) directory".
4. Copy `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` from the \bin folder to the same place where your `QtNetwork4.dll` or `QtNetworkd4.dll` is located.

Comment: Hi mattwritescode, i followed the same steps. i have been installed Win32OpenSSL_Light-1_0_1c.exe and copied libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from the \bin folder to Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySide folder. but still i can see the same error message

Comment: Are the path's correct? and have you restarted your machine since?

Comment: yes i have restarted my PC and i tried to run my script i got same error, i have copied (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) files to both places
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySide and C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PySide-1.0.1qt472-py2.7-win32.egg\PySide\                  actually i have QtNetwork4.dll file in these directory, so i copied here

Comment: and things may begin to be complicate if you want to distribute your application as executable through PyInstaller...